# In Postgres how do I write a SQL query to select distinct values overall but aggregated over a set time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I mean by this is if I have a table called payments with a `created_at` column and `user_id` column I want to select the count of purchases aggregated weekly (can be any interval I want) but only selecting first time purchases e.g. if a user purchased for the first time in week 1 it would be counted but if he purchased again in week 2 he would not be counted.

| created_at | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| timestamp | 1 |
| timestamp | 1 |

This is the query I came up with. The issue is if the user purchases multiple times they are all included. How can I improve this?

```
WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM generate_series(
      '2022-07-22T15:30:06.687Z'::DATE,
      '2022-11-21T17:04:59.457Z'::DATE,
      '1 week'
    ) date
)
SELECT 
    dates.date::DATE AS date, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)), 0) AS registrations
FROM
    dates
LEFT JOIN  
    payment ON created_at::DATE BETWEEN dates.date AND dates.date::date + '1 ${dateUnit}'::INTERVAL
GROUP BY 
    dates.date
ORDER BY 
    dates.date DESC;
```

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue, but you should also `group by dates.date::date`. Might be easier if you cast the result of `generate_series()` directly to a `date` in the CTE. Also: there is no need to enclose the column after a DISTINCT in parentheses

Comment: Note that `dates.date::date + '1 ${dateUnit}'::INTERVAL` can be simplified to `dates.date::date + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count only first purchases. So get those first purchases in the first step and work with these.

```
WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM generate_series(
      '2022-07-22T15:30:06.687Z'::DATE,
      '2022-11-21T17:04:59.457Z'::DATE,
      '1 week'
    ) date
)
, first_purchases AS
(
    SELECT user_id, MIN(created_at:DATE) AS purchase_date
    FROM payment
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT 
    d.date, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(p.purchase_date), 0) AS registrations
FROM
    dates d
LEFT JOIN  
    first_purchases p ON p.purchase_date >= d.date 
                     AND p.purchase_date <  d.date + '1 ${dateUnit}'::INTERVAL
GROUP BY 
    d.date
ORDER BY 
    d.date DESC;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! One small issue was that I had to count *something*. Counting * resulted in me being confused as 1's were added when there should have been 0's.

Comment: Ah, sorry, what a stupid mistake. I've corrected my answer accordingly for future readers.